# Swift could not find overload for 'init'ってなんですか？

Tags: swift

```
 if firstRandomNumber > secondRandomNumber {

       playerscoretotal += 1
        self.playerscore.text = String(playerscore)
    }
```

ここで

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

というエラーが出ます。

なぜでしょうか？

初心者です。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージを意訳すると、

> playerscoreの型は、String()の引数にはできないよ

となります。

質問から離れて、提示のコードのみ注目するなら、こう書きかえるのが妥当かと思います。

```
if firstRandomNumber > secondRandomNumber {
   playerscoretotal += 1
   self.playerscore.text = playerscore.description
}
```

`Printable`プロトコルを実装している型なら、かならずなにかしらの文字列（String型）を、`description`は返します。

Answer (score 1):

質問に対する回答という意味では本題から外れてしまいますが、
`playerscore.text`に`playerscore`を代入しているのがエラーの原因で、

```
self.playerscore.text = String(playerscore)
```

の部分は

```
self.playerscore.text = String(playerscoretotal)
```

とするのが本来想定している処理なのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

これでよいと思います。

```
self.playerscore.text = "\(playerscore)"
```